# Does "not in purview to provide authorization" mean I can post the picture to an editorial?

Tags: legal

I have recently contacted a shopping mall in Singapore to ask if I could post pictures in published based editorial on their grounds:

[Can I use pictures with shop windows in editorial?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/100883/can-i-use-pictures-with-shop-windows-in-editorial/100886?noredirect=1#comment188053_100886)

My original email:

> To whom it may concern,
>
> I was recently shopping with some friends in the Shoppes at Marina bay
>   sands and I saw some of the shop windows where very amazing.
>
> I didn't see any no photography sign inside the mall and thus having
>   my camera I took a few pictures with my friends.
>
> Some of them fit into a collection I am currently building for an
>   editorial. The goal of the editorial is to present the idea that
>   people do not use their surroundings enough when taking pictures.
>
> It will be published online on social media such as Instagram, Behance
>   and more.  I would also like to submit it as an article to submission
>   based magazines if possible (unpaid) and citing the location in the
>   credits.
>
> Thus I would like to know if it was allowed to post those pictures
>   since the Shoppes is probably private property I wanted to go through
>   the proper channels first.
>
> Here is an example of the photos:
>
> https://photos.app.goo.gl/bW9Hx7rfcekaRGfy5
>
> --  Best Regards,
>
> BURLET Médéric

And here is their reply:

> Hi Burlet,
>
> We have no comments on your pictures and is not in purview to provide
>   authorization.
>
> Best regards,
>
> filmphoto

I don't really get the meaning of this sentence. Does this mean I have the right to send those pictures to submission based magazines?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use pictures with shop windows in editorial?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/100883/can-i-use-pictures-with-shop-windows-in-editorial)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's really about the phrase "purview to provide authorization". I suggest https://english.stackexchange.com or https://ell.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not a lawyer, nor do I play one on TV, but to me that reads as

> We don't have the authority to say yes or no.

[Purview](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/purview) is legalese for 'jurisdiction' or 'authority'

If you wrote to the mall owners, that may mean you need to instead get permission directly from each shop owner; but it's so terse that all it's really saying is "not my problem, go away."