# Do I need permission to take photos of my work

Tags: permission

I am a builder based in the UK and often take photos of my completed work with the intention to post on my website. I have recently had a client complain, do I need permission?

Comment: I'd suggest that "not annoying your clients" is probably more important than the legal position here.

Comment: I do agree with you Phillip, I am just curious

Comment: **A lawyer will be the best option to answer that**, but in general: Either write it clearly in the contract or ask your clients if it is okay - that will make them happy. Law-based: I don't know about the UK, but here in the German-speaking world, the general _rule of thumb_ is that you can make photos of almost anything from public space (e.g. streets), while you need permission if you do so in private space.

Comment: I totally see this from the client's point of view. I don't want a photo of my toilet on some website for all my neighbours to see. I'd rather use a (potentially more expensive) builder who respects my privacy. Be nice, rather than going down the "I'm legally entitled" path. Essentially, I agree with @Philip - ask, and respect the client's wishes. My opinion.

Comment: Closely related (but US instead of UK): [Who owns the copyright of a picture taken of my construction work?](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/29849)

Comment: @flolilo: you can take pictures, but that doesn't mean you can publish them. In France, you can take pictures of recent monuments, but you cannot publish them without the consent of the architects.

Comment: @xenoid This is an issue  that some countries have - but the [German-speaking world, again, is pretty liberal when it comes to this.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedom_of_panorama#/media/File:Freedom_of_Panorama_world_map.svg)

Comment: Most problems with taking images in private (rather than public) places have to do with trespassing (even if the owner of the property has allowed you to be there, but only under certain conditions, continuing to do things the owner has asked you not to do constitutes trespassing in many legal jurisdictions). For more, please see: [Can I use pictures with shop windows in editorial?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/100883/15871)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you do need permission in the UK to take pictures in private places such as houses.  I can't find really definitive evidence to back this up, but [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photography_and_the_law#United_Kingdom) is fairly definite about it (but has the dreaded 'citation needed' note), as is [this site](http://www.photographers-resource.co.uk/photography/Legal/Access_Rights.htm).

(Disclaimer: I'm not a lawyer.)

Comment: It could make a difference if you are standing on the property or on public land when you take the photo.

Comment: @lijat Yes, it does I think.  I was assuming the person was on private property when taking the picture.